# Showing that $R/[R,R]$ is commutative

Tags: ring-theory

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1$, and let $[R,R]$ be the ideal generated by the set
$$
\{ \ xy-yx \ : \ x,y \in R \ \} 
$$
Show that $R/[R,R]$ is commutative.

---

Before I show what I did, I wan't to find out if I understood how such an ideal is defined. I know that for a sequence that ends somewhere the ideal is defined as follows.
$$
(x_1, \cdots ,x_n) 
\quad = \quad 
\{ \ r_1x_1 + \cdots r_nx_n \ : \ r_1, \cdots + r_n \in R \ \}
$$

For an infinite set, I guess that just finitely many elements are allowed to be non-zero but I still doubt about it a bit.

---

I understand that I need to pick $x,y \in R,$ and than I need two find some $r \in [R,R]$ such that $xy = ryx$. That would mean that $r=xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$, a commutator as I them from group theory. Can you help me to find the right element?

**Adjustment** I messed up something. I should find an $r$ such that $xy + r = yx$, instead of finding an $r$ that satisfies $xy =ryx$. Everything is easier now.

Comment: I think you might mis-typed the first sentence, $R$ is a <del>commutative</del> ring.

Comment: cosets formed by ideals are additive, not multiplicative. In other words, the coset containing $r$ is $r + I$, not $rI$. You need to fix your equation $xy = ryx$. Do you see how to do this?

Comment: now I understand everything, thank you

Comment: Then feel free to answer your own question!

Comment: The hole question vanishes now that I have noticed this mistake, the whole think is a triviality. I think I'd better erase it.

Comment: Whoops, too late to do so. Somebody has already given an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mod out by $[R,R]$, then $\overline{xy-yx}=\overline{xy}-\overline{yx}=\overline{x}\overline{y}-\overline{y}\overline{x}=\overline{0}$. Whence $\overline{x}\overline{y}=\overline{y}\overline{x}$.